# Remove space from String in number format

Tags: java, string, numbers

My Question is very simple, why we cannot remove the space in String if it is in number format ?

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        long num=12366271;
        String b = "this is an example";
        NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance();
        String a= format.format(num);

        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(a.replaceAll(" ",""));
        System.out.println(b.replaceAll(" ",""));
    }
```

The space in the sentance is removed with a simple `replace`, while the number format is not.

Comment: Does it contain spaces? Maybe it contains [non-breaking spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space), which are a different character from `' '`.

Comment: What spaces?  http://ideone.com/XjA82n

Comment: May be ? this is why I ask the question :)

Comment: You have formatted num variable (long type) which definitely has no space. So there is no space to remove.

Comment: I found the response.Thank you.
Because it is a non-breaking spaces. And to replace it, we need to make \u00a0. So replace("\u00a0", "").

Comment: System.out.println(a.replaceAll(String.valueOf(a.charAt(2)),""));

Comment: What is output of it?